# What is the solution to "Input contain NaN" when encoding categorical columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, categorical-data, data-preprocessing

I always get *Input contains NaN* whenever I run `encoder.transform` in my jupyter notebook. It works perfectly ok on google-colab.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore').fit(inputs_df[categorical_cols])
encoded_cols = list(encoder.get_feature_names(categorical_cols))
inputs_df[encoded_cols] = encoder.transform(inputs_df[categorical_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

Behavior env-dependent often means some dependencies have different versions installed.

It would help to add context when asking a question: lib used, etc. Aside from that, the solution is probably to avoid having NaNs in your input. Looks like sklearn, but not knowing the context, all I can do is point to google keywords that can help you.
"sklearn remove NaN". "numpy nan_to_num".